# PostgreSQL “syntax error at end of input” after INSERT INTO with ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE condition

Tags: java, postgresql, upsert

I am trying to write an UPSERT code on my PostgreSQL DB.

Using

> NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

I recieve the following error message:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [


INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
(ID,DATE_TIMESTAMP,ENVIRONMENT,REGION,ORGANIZATION,ARRIVAL_TIMESTAMP,LAST_UPDATED) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 
ON CONFLICT (ID, DATE_TIMESTAMP, ENVIRONMENT, REGION)
DO UPDATE

]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input] with the root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input
```

The query:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
(ID,DATE_TIMESTAMP,ENVIRONMENT,REGION,ORGANIZATION,ARRIVAL_TIMESTAMP,LAST_UPDATED) 
VALUES (:ID,:DATE_TIMESTAMP,:ENVIRONMENT,:REGION,:ORGANIZATION,:ARRIVAL_TIMESTAMP,:LAST_UPDATED) 
ON CONFLICT (ID, DATE_TIMESTAMP, ENVIRONMENT, REGION)
DO UPDATE
```

I've tried without the conflict condition, worked well.

I've tried adding a SET command, didn't work.

I've also tried using setters after the DO UPDATE SET statement 
I've also tried your solution, adding a SET statement for each column I want to update, using EXCLUDED.COLUMN_NAME

I received the following error message:

```
ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
```

Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: Please post the full INSERT statement. The  [Do Update](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-insert.html) must be followed by the appropriate set statement(s). That is missing from post. Does it exist in actual statement.

Comment: I've added my query

Comment: I found a solution, posted it. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

The reason for the error was the constraint I chose.

The CONFLICT condition must be a CONSTRAINT. For example, the primary keys.

See full documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html

> ON CONFLICT can be used to specify an alternative action to raising a unique constraint or exclusion constraint violation error. (See ON CONFLICT Clause below.)